# template not found, deploying Pyramid on Webfaction

Tags: python, pyramid, webfaction

I'm trying to deploy my webapp to Webfaction, the basic example is working correctly, I got a TemplateNotFound in a template that extends a basic template using Jinja2. Here is my project tree:

```
/webapps
    /myapp
        development.ini
        production.ini
        /bin
    /theapp
        /Project
          setup.py
          /project
              __init__.py
              views.py
              /templates
                  base.jinja2
                  home.jinja2
              /static
```

**_*init*_.py**

```
config.include('pyramid_jinja2')
config.add_jinja2_search_path("templates")
```

**home.jinja2**

```
{% extends "templates/base.jinja2" %}
```

To be more clear, the project works locally I know it's something with the template path, I'm not sure how to set it, I tried many different ways, anyways this is the traceback:

```
  File "..webapps/myapp/myapp/Project/project/templates/home.jinja2", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends "templates/base.jinja2" %}
  File "..webapps/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_jinja2-1.8-py2.7.egg/pyramid_jinja2/__init__.py", line 193, in get_source
    raise TemplateNotFound(name=ex.name, message=message)
TemplateNotFound: templates/base.jinja2; asset=..webapps/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Project-0.0-py2.7.egg/project/templates/base.jinja2; searchpath=['..webapps/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Project-0.0-py2.7.egg/project/templates']
```

Please help me set the correct path to templates, if that is my mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the search path is `'..webapps/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Project-0.0-py2.7.egg/project/templates'`, that tells me you installed your application as an egg using `python setup.py install`. By far the most common pitfall of distributing your app in this way is that it requires a MANIFEST.in file when packaging your application in order for it to include static assets. `python setup.py develop` runs the application out of the directory instead, and does not suffer from that problem. I expect that if you unzip your egg file you will not find your templates inside.

Comment: Exactly, there is no /templates inside the egg file

Comment: Thanks for the response, actually what fixed it was adding `*.jinja2` to MANIFEST.in

Answer (score 1):

Try add in file MANIFEST.in the extesion files.

```
recursive-include project *.ico *.png *.css *.gif *.jpg *.pt *.txt *.mak *.mako *.js *.html *.xml *.jinja2
```